# How do I get a id of a <span> if i have id of div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having **"div"** which contains **span** so i want id of that particular span

```
<div id="status-0" class="abc">
    <span id="span_id" class="xyz" title="Enabled">&nbsp;</span>
</div>                                                                                         So how to get id of span with jquery?   and after some action i want to change class of that span using id, how to do that?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use this:

```
var id = $('div span').attr('id');
```

It uses CSS selector(descendant) and apply the attribute function on the matching element.

If you have data on the div you can use it to narrow the results:

```
var id = $('#status-0 span').attr('id');
```

Changing class is with:

```
.attr('class', 'value');
```

Adding class is with:

```
.addClass('value');
```

Comment: use if u got div id in another jquery variable                  span_id = $('#'+div_id+' span').attr('id');

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

`var id = $("div span").attr("id");`

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the some `id` / `class` to div or span to make it more precise selection. If it is not possible you can use parent child selector.

```
id = $('div > span').attr('id'); // span is direct child
```

or

```
id = $('div span').attr('id'); // span is descendant
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var spanID = $("#yourdivid span").attr("id") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use that div id to get id of span

```
var id = $('#div').find('span').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know the index of the span under the div better use with *eq*. you can use *nth-child* also instead of *eq*.

```
$('$yourDivID span:eq(<<index>>)').attr('id');
```

In other case if you have the class of the span you can try the following

```
$('$yourDivID span.spanClass').attr('id');
```